# network programming / message framing

Tags: c, sockets, flags

I have a short question about message framing for network programming:

You often see implementations that define a MAGIC flag and a corresponding bitmask to retrieve it.

The header may contain other message relevant information, flipping the bits with logical OR.

Various implementations check for the magic flag using (header & MASK) == MAGIC.

What is the benefit of seperating these concerns?

You could also do: (header & MAGIC) == MAGIC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple example:

```
MASK   = 0x000F
MAGIC  = 0x0001
header = 0x0005
```

Then `(header & MASK) == MAGIC` checks if all bits that are set in MASK (here the lower 4 bits) have the *same value* as the corresponding bits in MAGIC. This is **not true** for
the example header.

On the other hand, `(header & MAGIC) == MAGIC` checks only if all bits that are set in the MAGIC are also set in the header, which **is true** in this example.

In your example, `header = 0xFFFF` would pass the test `(header & MAGIC) == MAGIC`,
but not the test `(header & MASK) == MAGIC`.

Of course there is no difference if MASK == MAGIC.

Comment: makes perfectly sense.